# Getting error "variable veryFar might not have been initialized" with BigInteger

Tags: java, android

I am making a converter which will convert numbers to text. I did everything as said in this [website](https://developer360.net/java-program-convert-number-to-words-android-studio/) and edited for using big Integers but it is then showing a variable is not initialized.

I edited some things to make it compatible with big integers for bigger numbers, but it just shows variable veryFar maybe not initialized. (I edited the variable name to try fix it!).

```java
package com.example.convertnumbertotext;

import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class EnglishNumberToWords {

    private static BigInteger bi = new BigInteger("100");
    private static BigInteger bi2 = new BigInteger("20");
    private static BigInteger bi3 = new BigInteger("10");
    private static final String[] tensNames = { "", " ten", " twenty", " thirty", " forty",
            " fifty", " sixty", " seventy", " eighty", " ninety" };

    private static final String[] numNames = { "", " one", " two", " three", " four", " five",
            " six", " seven", " eight", " nine", " ten", " eleven", " twelve", " thirteen",
            " fourteen", " fifteen", " sixteen", " seventeen", " eighteen", " nineteen" };

    private static String convertLessThanOneThousand(BigInteger number) {
        String veryFar;
        BigInteger[] bii = number.divideAndRemainder(bi);
        BigInteger[] bii2 = number.divideAndRemainder(bi3);
        int resut = bii[1].compareTo(bi2);

        if (resut == -1) {
            veryFar = numNames[bii[1].intValue()];

            number = number.divide(bi);
        } else if (resut == 1 || resut == 0) {
            veryFar = numNames[bii2[1].intValue()];
            number = number.divide(bi3);

            veryFar = tensNames[bii2[1].intValue()] + veryFar;
            number = number.divide(bi3);
        }
        if (number.compareTo(BigInteger.valueOf(0)) == 0)
            return veryFar;
            return numNames[number.intValue()] + " hundred" + veryFar;
    }

}
```

It shows 2 same error messages-
error: variable veryFar might not have been initialized
error: variable veryFar might not have been initialized

Comment: string variable must be initialized when you declare. as far as error concern just say `String veryFar = ""; ` i think that will fix the issue

Comment: You have not initialized it, which might cause problems: `String veryFar;` is just a declaration, it does not set any value. If you just want to avoid the *error messages*, then write `String veryFar = "";`.

Comment: You initialize `veryFar` only if `result` is `0`, `1` or `-1`. It means that if none of these conditions is met, your variable won't be initialized, hence the error.

Comment: Thank you all !! Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trimmed down, you have this code:

> ```
> String veryFar;
> ...
> if (resut == -1) {
>     veryFar = numNames[bii[1].intValue()];
>     ...
> } else if (resut == 1 || resut == 0) {
>     veryFar = numNames[bii2[1].intValue()];
>     ...
> }
> ```

If result is not -1, 0, or 1, neither of these blocks will be executed. In that case, `veryFar` will never be assigned a value.

Either initialize it when you declare it (like `String veryFar = null`) or add an `else` case that assigns a value to it.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the contract of `compareTo` is that it returns `<0`, `0` or `>0`, *not* `-1`, `0` or `1`.

Comparing to -1 and 1 exactly may work sometimes, but it wouldn't work in general (e.g. it wouldn't work for comparing Strings), and is brittle to changes in internal implementation details of the class.

As such, change your conditions to:

```
if (resut < 0) { // instead of == -1
  // ...
} else { // instead of == 0 || == 1
  // ...
}
```

Then your variable will always be initialized.